# Bending an arrow in circuiTikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows, circuitikz

I've made a circuit with circuiTikz and **I have the following problem: how to bend the arrow which is above number 1?** Here is the photo of the circuit:[image: circuit]

So how to bend the arrow to get an arrow something like this:[image: arrow]

I give you the coding I've made so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\definecolor{a}{rgb}{.75,.75,.75}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw[color=a,dashed](-8,-8)grid(8,8);
%\draw[fill=black](0,0)circle[radius=.55mm];
\draw
(0,0)node[transformer core](T){}
(T.A1)to[lamp](-4,0)
      to[L,l=45 mT](-4,-2.1)
      to[short](T.A2)
;

\draw
(-3.5,0)to[short,*-](-3.5,2)
        to[voltmeter](-1.5,2)
        to[short,-*](-1.5,0)
;

\draw
(T.B1)to[short](4,0)
      to[vsourcesin,l=110 V](4,-2.1)
      to[push button](T.B2)
;

\draw
(-1,-2.1)to[short,*-](-1,-4)
         to[empty led](-3.5,-4)
         to[short,-*](-3.5,-2.1)
;

\draw[thick,-latex](.4,.2)--(-.4,.2);
\node[below]at(0,.2){1};
\draw(0,.4)node{\footnotesize 1.4 V$\leftarrow$ 110 V};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

Please, do not change the codes, just bend the arrow which is above number 1. You can change the codes if you have a much much better way to draw it. Help me out of this, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of lines in your MWE

```
\draw[thick,-latex](.4,.2)--(-.4,.2);
\node[below]at(0,.2){1};
\draw(0,.4)node{\footnotesize 1.4 V$\leftarrow$ 110 V};
```

try, if the following gives, what you like to obtain:

```
\draw[thick,-latex,shorten >=2mm, shorten <=2mm,in=30, out=150] 
    (T.north east) to node[above] {\footnotesize 1.4 V $\leftarrow$ 110 V} (T.north west);
```

[image]